# Pass data from activity A to activity B

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult

Here's what I want to do: I have a quiz where the user has to answer three questions. After the three questions, there is a result screen where the user sees what he has answered.

So I want to get the answer from activity A, activity B and activity C to the result activity. The only problem is that every example or tutorial on the internet is going from activity A to activity B and then back to activity A. But I don't want to get back, I want to go forward. Is this even possible?

In my question one activity (activity A) I have this code. The intent data is send to the second question instead of the result screen as mentioned above, purely to test if the onActivityResult() works. The code below is inside an if/else statement, to check for the correct answer.

**QuestionOneActivity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(QuestionOne.this, QuestionTwo.class);
    i.putExtra("result", buttonText);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    startActivityForResult(i, CONTROLE_CODE);

Log.e("Send", "Send");
```

The `buttonText` variable is the answer that the user chooses. I already checked if this variable is null, and it isn't. The `CONTROLE_CODE` variable is set to 0;

And in my QuestionTwoActivity (activity B), there is this code to receive the data from

**QuestionTwoActivity:**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == CONTROLE_CODE)) {
            retrieveData = data.getStringExtra("result");
            Log.e("Data", "Data: " + retrieveData);
        }

        Log.e("The answer is:", "The answer is" + retrieveData);
    }
```

The `retrieveData` is a String variable and is declared at the top of my Activity.

The `Log.e("Send", "Send");` from the QuestionOneActivity is visible in my LogCat. But the `Log.e("Data", "Data: " + retrieveData);` or `Log.e("The answer is:", "The answer is" + retrieveData);` from the QuestionTwoActivity isn't shown in my LogCat. So it doesn't get invoked.

Maybe this is a duplicate question, but I didn't find the answer for my problem. So what is the correct way to send data from Activity A, Activity B and Activity C to a result screen (Activity D)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Question 1

```
Intent i = new Intent(QuestionOne.this, QuestionTwo.class);
i.putExtra("answer1", buttonText);
startActivity(i);
```

in oncreate function of question2 get previous answer

```
String Answer1 =  getIntent().getStringExtra("answer1");
Intent i = new Intent(QuestionTwo.this, QuestionThree.class);
i.putExtra("answer1", Answer1 );
i.putExtra("answer2", buttonText);
startActivity(i);
```

and so on for question three and then result

Comment: Thanks! this also worked very well. Do you have any idea why I don't have to use onActivityResult? Because we used this during class and it was also in some example code the teacher gave us.

Comment: onActivityResult is used to pass data to the previous activity which you can collect in this function, e.g. if you want to select a photo you start gallery activity for result expecting it will return you image path

Answer (score 0):

Activity `QuestionOne`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(QuestionOne.this, QuestionTwo.class);
i.putExtra("result", buttonText);
startActivity(i);
```

Activity `QuestionTwo`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text = intent.getStringExtra("result");
```

Comment: Is it seriously that simple? Don't you have to use onActivityResult? If not, do you know why not?

Comment: @KevinKromjong Yes, it's simple. Just try it.